# Inequality harmonic and geometric mean

Tags: means

I'm trying to understand the proof on the bottom:

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality

He uses the AM-GM inequality to prove the HG-GM-inequality, but I don't see how he manages to rewrite the sum like he did. Can anybody help me out on that?

Comment: *What* sum?....

Comment: The sum after "The inequality ... is a direct consequence of AM-GM"

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_i=\sqrt[n]{\frac{x_1\cdots x_n}{x_i^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}}{x_i}$. Then by the AM-GM inequality,

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_iy_i&\ge\sqrt[n]{y_1\cdots y_n}\\
&=\sqrt[n]{\prod_i\frac{\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}}{x_i}}\\
&=\sqrt[n]{\frac{x_1\cdots x_n}{x_1\cdots x_n}}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

As $\sum_iy_i=\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}\sum_i\frac{1}{x_i}$, cross multiplying gives $$\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}\ge\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\root n\of{\frac{x_1\cdots x_n}{x_i^n}} = 
\frac{\root n\of{{x_1\cdots x_n}}}{\root n\of{x_i^n}} = \cdots$$